# Redirection URL callback is not working in SFSafariviewcontroller

Tags: ios, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm facing the below issues with  WKWebView & SFSafariViewController.

- Camera interface is showing blank but functionality is working fine
  with SFSafariViewController
- Camera itself is not working with the wkwebview.
- Not able to receive Call backs after initialLoadDidRedirectToURL in
  the webpage internal navigation (Safari view controller).

**Logs** [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1

[image]

Please help me in getting the callback so that will close the safariviewcontroller automatically.

Here is the code

```
- (void)openLink:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if (url) {
        if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil && !safariViewController) {
            safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
            // [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url configuration:SFSafariViewControllerConfiguration];
            safariViewController.delegate = self;
            [self presentViewController:safariViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller initialLoadDidRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)URL{
    NSLog(@"URL %@",URL);
}
- (void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller didCompleteInitialLoad:(BOOL)didLoadSuccessfully {
    NSLog(@"didCompleteInitialLoad");
}
- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller{
    NSLog(@"safariViewControllerDidFinish");
}

- (IBAction)loadWebview:(id)sender {
    [self openLink:@"http://xxxxx"];
}
```